# DotNetNuke Azure Web Site from Gallery SQL Azure connection error

Tags: database-connection, dotnetnuke, azure-sql-database, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to create an Azure Web site using the DotNetNuke Community Edition 6.2.2 from the app Gallery, but I got an error when trying to connect to the newly created SQL Azure db. This are the steps I followed:

1. Log in to manage.windowsazure.com
2. Go to Web Sites, click the "+" button, and then "From Gallery".
3. Select "DotNetNuke Community Edition" from the app gallery.
4. Configure App: Url (Ex. x12.azurewebsites.net), Database: Create a new SQL Database, Region: East US, Subscription: An_Enterprise_Subscription., click the -> arrow.
5. Specific database setting: Left Name with default, select a Server in the same Region, enter a username(Ex. my_user), enter a password (my_pass) Note: password without "=" sign., click the check mark to finish, and the site start provisioning and deploying without problems.
6. After a couple of minutes the management site said the site was running.
7. Open the x12.azurewebsites.net on a browser.
8. After a few seconds, the installation page is shown with the following message in red: The Auto option has been disabled as the DotNetNuke Application cannot connect to a valid SQL Server database. You can continue to use either of the other two Wizard options and configure the Database settings at the appropriate Wizard step.
9. Click Next twice to reach the "Configure Database Connection" page.
10. Select Database: SQL Server 2005/2008 Database, Server: tcp:x12.database.windows.net,1433, Database: x12. This data came from the database connection string on the Windows Azure management site(manage.windowsazure.com). Using the default parameters for the rest.
11. The following error is shown:

Connection Error(s):
Index #: 0
Source: .Net SqlClient Data Provider
Class: 11
Number: 0
Message:

On the Web Site management connection string the following connection string is found:
Data Source=tcp:x12.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=x12;User Id=my_user;Password=my_password;

Instead of the following connection string provided by the db management:
Server=tcp:x12.database.windows.net,1433;Database=x12;User ID=my_user@x12;Password=my_password;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;Connection Timeout=30;

I changed the connection string to the second one with no success.
The SQL Azure server x12 has a firewall rule to allow all azure related connection (0.0.0.0 to 0.0.0.0) and a rule to allow my IP to manage the server.

I installed DotNetNuke Community Edition 6.2.2 on a Windows 2012 VM on Azure, and I got a similar problem, but in that case I fixed it by running the application pool with a local user with access to the db.

Thank you very much for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the web site, there was a connection string with the same name the db has on DotNetNuke. After changing that connection string name to "SiteSqlServer", and SQLServer as provided instead of SQLAzure. I didn't get any results using the connection string found on the db management.

In order to make it work, I needed to revisit step 10(see question), and configure the database without integrated security, and use the user@the_db_server. In my example, my_user@x12. This started the the db installation process and regular DotNetNuke installation. There were no visible changes on the site web.config.